# Cannot access Azure without VPN

Tags: vpn, azure, rdp, azure-networking

I'm having trouble accessing my VM (hosted in East Asia, HK) after obtaining a new public IP address. I'm in mainland China (and thus behind the Great Firewall - not sure if this is relevant). I was able to RDP to it fine previously. But after getting the new public IP, there have been connection problems.

I still receive the prompt asking me if I want to connect given the invalid certificate. I say YES. And then RDP gives me the 0x204 error.

However, if I first use a HK VPN and then try to RDP to my VM it connects fine.

I have already tried obtaining a new IP address from my home ISP provider (in case Azure was blacklisting my IP for some reason). But this didn't help.

So my question is: is there any reason to think that Azure is preventing all IPs originating from China to connect o my VM? And if so, how can I stop this? As I said, I was able to use it fine previously

Comment: I'm bit qualified to answer this, but it seems to me more likely to be related to the great firewall. Sounds like it might be mitm'ing the connection but not understanding the protocol and causing breakage?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is an Azure problem, I think it is a Great Firewall issue. If your getting the certificate warning then you are able to make the initial connection to the machine, which indicates there is no IP level block at the Azure side. The fact that your RDP connection fails points at something blocking that at the firewall level.